# What is "User was removed"?

Tags: support

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but I just noticed in my profile the following item

```
-65  01:55  removed          User was removed
```

https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/90/systemdown?tab=reputation

What is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just means that a previously active user asked for his account to be deleted and consequently all reputation given or taken due to his voting was undone.

In this case, they upvoted your questions and answers to give you 65 reputation. When they left, that reputation obliterated. There's [a discussion on the StackOverflow meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it) about this if you want to hear from people on both sides (love and hate it).

Comment: I don't really mind the point reduction. I was just worried that something was wrong with my user, or that it was removed at some point. Thanks! I'll accept this answer as soon as the pesky time limit goes away :)